# How to share component between multiple Ember projects

Tags: ember.js

I need to share component between two Ember projects, but it is possible to achieve that without generating and publishing node package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, it is possible to avoid npm. You can host the code on Github or Bitbucket or maybe any git-based system.

The **Install command** would look like this

```
ember install git+ssh://git@bitbucket.org:path-to-git-repository.git
```

Optionally you can reference specific commit like this

```
ember install git+ssh://git@bitbucket.org:path-to-git-repository.git#commit-id
```

The updated package.json will then look something like this

**package.json**

```
"devDependencies": {
    "your-package-name": "git+ssh://git@bitbucket.org:path-to-git-repository.git",
}
```